# Compile and run Angular Project?

Tags: angular

Im not familiar working with angular projects,I have got one new angular project which is partially completed and i tried to run the project using Angular cli ,I have tried all the possible way that i have found on web .I tried [This method](https://scotch.io/tutorials/use-the-angular-cli-for-faster-angular-2-projects) Shows some warning

```
``-- angular-cli@1.0.0-beta.28.3 `-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY rxjs@^5.0.1
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 
(node_modules\angular-cli\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for 
fsevents@1.1.1: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: { 
"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN @angular/core@2.4.10 requires a peer of rxjs@^5.0.1 but none was 
installed.`
```

When i using 
    `npm install npm start` 
    Shows some errors

```
`npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.14393
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program 
Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
npm ERR! node v6.10.3
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! my-dream-app@0.0.0 start: ng serve
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the my-dream-app@0.0.0 start script 'ng serve'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the my-dream-app 
package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     ng serve
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project 
with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs my-dream-app
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls my-dream-app
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\PC\Desktop\my-dream-app\npm-debug.log`
```

[image: Structure of the project]

How can i compile and run the project?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you installed local packages successful but fail on run project.
You can try this command :

```
ng serve

// or an even shorter version
ng s
```

In case you need, please ref to this doc to get right setup for angular-cli
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#prerequisites

Comment: when using `ng serve` shows "you have to be inside an angular-cli project in order to use the serve command."

Comment: Did you install angular-cli, unless please run this command first: `npm install -g @angular/cli` . And cd to inside project and run `ng serve` .

Comment: @borislemke Yes

Comment: @ThienHoang Now i got msg "Comiled successfully"

Comment: @ThienHoangYes it is

Comment: @AjithVManali ok good to hear that, please mark that it's right answer :)